# NSString combine date and name as the name of a csv

Tags: ios, csv

I have an iOS app that gets data from a form and then sends it as a csv via email. currently it saves the csv as a static file name but i want it to start saving it as `<date><other app defined variable>.csv`.  If its easier to redefine a new variable for the date then so be it, have tried it but couldn't make that work either.

Currently it looks like this:

```
NSString* fileName = @"file.csv";
```

I have tried this, among other minor syntax changes with no luck:

```
NSString* fileName = @"%@%@ .csv",FromEmail,dateString;
```

FromEmail is defined in HomeView.m like this:

```
NSString *FromEmail = [userDefault objectForKey:@"FromEmail"];
```

This is the whole csv making part:

```
//CSV function
    NSMutableString *csv = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    //add your content to the csv
    [csv appendFormat:@"From,Date,Client,Time,Notes,Hardware,AfterHours,NoCharge\n%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",FromEmail,dateString,txtClient.text,txtTime.text,txtNotes.text,txtHardware.text,isAfterHours,isDiscount];
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSString* fileName = @"file.csv";
    NSString* fileName = @"%@%@ .csv",FromEmail,dateString;
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    BOOL res = [[csv dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];

    if (!res) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Creating CSV" message:@"Check your permissions to make sure this app can create files so you may email the app data" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Data saved! File path = %@", fileName);
        [picker addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath]
                     mimeType:@"text/csv"
                     fileName:@"file.csv"];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
//END CSV Function
```

I suspect its something really simple but its just had me stumped for ages

Comment: What does look like the `fileName` with an example? My guess is that there is a character not allowed. Maybe the "@"?

Comment: So `dateString` just materializes out of thin air?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @HotLicks dateString is defined with:
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:newDate1 ];
newDate1 is defined further up as an NSDate

Comment: @Larme I don't quite understand what you are asking.. do you mean that the code for that line looks like it should work if the first @ is removed?

Comment: Still useless.  What is the date format???

Comment: This is the section that does the date calculation:

   `NSDate *now = [NSDate date];`
    `NSDate *newDate1 = [NSDate date];`
    `int daysAgoNum = [daysAgo.text intValue];`
    `int daysAgoNumNegative = abs(daysAgoNum) * (-1);`
    `newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysAgoNumNegative];`

Answer (score 0):

Hot Licks was right, I had the format of the date wrong.  It was throwing an error because the date section was formatted with forward slashes which was changing the path it was being saved at.

I added a separate date formatter for the CSV file name with this code:

```
NSDate *csvDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *csvFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[csvFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyy-Hm"];
NSString *csvDateString = [csvFormatter stringFromDate:csvDate ];
```

And changed the line making the filename variable to this:

```
NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.csv",FromEmail,csvDateString];
```

Thanks for the help